# Unsupported calendar when reading in NetCDF file using Iris in Python

Tags: python, error-handling, calendar, netcdf

I am trying to load a NetCDF file into python using `iris.load`.
When I try to load the file I get this error:

```
Value error: u'360' is an unsupported calendar.
```

Any ideas how I can resolve this error?

Thank you!

Comment: This means the file has a calendar which is not CF-compliant. You will need to modify the calendar. This can be done using CDO, but you will need to revise the question to give more info on the calendar

Comment: Yuu can process your file in `cdo` first before opeing/loading it in Python.             Simply use ```cdo -a setcalendar,standard ifile.nc ofile.nc```